# Electron (atom shell) window getting closed on its own after some time

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

Just a plain Hello World application using electron-prebuilt is set up.
I run it by `npm start` command.

Window shows up as expected normally. However it is getting closed on it's own after some time.

**In command prompt it is throwing the following warnings before window is getting closed:**

```
WARNING:raw_channel_win.cc(473)] WriteFile: The pipe is being closed. (0xE8)
WARNING:channel.cc(549)] Failed to send message to ack remove remote endpoint (local ID 1, remote ID 1)
WARNING:channel.cc(315)] RawChannel write error
```

What is causing this issue?

npm version is 1.4.10 & node (via io.js) version is 0.11.13 (Windows 7 x64)

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but my first Electron app kept closing after exactly 1 minute due to garbage collection of the window object. I fixed it by making the variable that references the window a global variable

Comment: Thanks Oztaco! Was completely baffled, but this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Oztaco stated, in the [QuickStart Guide](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.28.0/tutorial/quick-start/) it has the following code sample:

```
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the javascript object is GCed.
var mainWindow = null;

// This method will be called when Electron has done everything
// initialization and ready for creating browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  // other code ommited

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```